# Why is catch() block not running in Objection.js queries and instead then() always runs passing either 0 or 1 as a result?

Tags: javascript, sql, express, knex.js, objection.js

So when running a query using Objection.js, the query will return data based on success or failure of said query and this data is passed to the then() block as a 0 or 1. Meaning to error handle, I'm having to check falsey values rather than send a response in the catch block. Am I doing something wrong?

```
const editIndustry = async (req, res, next) => {
    const industry = await Industry.query().findById(req.params.industryId);

    if (!industry) {
        return res.status(404).json({
            error: 'NotFoundError',
            message: `industry not found`,
        });
    }
    await industry
        .$query()
        .patch({ ...req.body })
        .then(result => console.log(result, 'then() block'))
        // never runs
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            next(err);
        });
};
```

```
App is listening on port 3000.
1 then() block ran
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working as expected. The reason it's not going into the catch block is because there isn't an error. `patch` does not return the row. It returns the number of rows changed ([see docs](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/mutate-methods.html#patch)).

The function I think you're really looking for is `patchAndFetchById` ([see docs](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/mutate-methods.html#patchandfetchbyid)). If you're concerned about generating a 404 error, you can append `throwIfNotFound`. Obviously, this will throw if it's not found in the database, which will let you catch. You can catch an instance of this error so you can send a proper 404 response. Otherwise, you want to return a 500. You'd need to require `NotFoundError` from objection.

```
const { NotFoundError } = require('objection');
const Industry = require('<myIndustryModelLocation>');

const editIndustry = (req, res) => {
  try {

    return Industry
        .query()
        .patchAndFetchById(req.params.industryId, { ...req.body })
        .throwIfNotFound();

  } catch (err) {

    if(err instanceof NotFoundError) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        error: 'NotFoundError',
        message: `industry not found`,
      });
    }

    return res.status(500);
  }
};
```

Comment: OP here!

Thanks for the help, I see now, my mistake was that the return value is rows.

I used your code, but had to update it using async await in order for it to work as the calls are asynchronous. Additionally I had to use $query on the response as I'm using the unique validation module which can only perform validation on $query.

Comment: I understand - I didn't include async/await because `Industry.query()` returns a promise which means async/await shouldn't be required there. If you included it, it would basically just be wrapping the promise returned by objection. However, if you do multiple queries in your request, you'll definitely need to use async/await. Glad to know your issue is resolved! Can you mark it as resolved?

Comment: Yeah I guess, but I didnt really understand it before, now I do understand a little more. And so wrote it in a more sensible way for myself

What do you mean 'returns a promise' doesnt that still need to be awaited or .then() ?

Will resolve it now, thanks again!